# relationship between rows in sql table

Tags: sql, database

i'm wondering if there is a way to relate between rows in the same table.
for example: i want to store a keywords in the database and make every single keyword points to others which are related to it. (instead of creating a table to every single keyword and add related keywords to it)
if not, hope anyone can suggest an idea to store keyword and relate between them with minimum size.
Thanks,

Comment: Add an extra column, which for each row will store the id/primary key of the row its related to. This would only be useful if you want to relate a row with another single row.

Comment: but the problem is that every keyword has lot of related ones (more than 10,000), in other words, every keyword (every row) would have an "array" of 10,000 ids. this is massive storage.

Comment: You want to store the relations, so you can't avoid the storage. Having an array of ids sounds bad, a better approach would be to have a row for each distinct relation.